# A recursion problem of python in the first project(hog) of cs61a

Tags: python

I'm stuck on understanding the recursion code:

```
def make_test_dice(*outcomes):

def dice():
    nonlocal index
    index = (index + 1) % len(outcomes) 
    return outcomes[index]
return dice
```

(In the terminal)If I make `dice = make_test_dice(*outcomes)` and `type dice()` I will get 1, but I don't understand why I continue to `type dice()` I will get 2, and then 3, and 1.... 
1. How does this recursion happen?
2. What is the mechanism of this recursion from the second `type dice()`?

Regards thanks in advance!

Comment: is this the complete code? `index` is not defined outside the function scope but it is defined as `nonlocal`. also the indentation is either wrong or you omitted some of your code.

Answer (score 2):

At the very least, you need to initialize `index` so `nonlocal index` doesn't raise a syntax error, since there *is* no nonlocal variable by that name.

```
def make_test_dice(*outcomes):
    index = -1
    def dice():
        nonlocal index
        index = (index + 1) % len(outcomes) 
        return outcomes[index]
    return dice
```

Now if you define

```
d = make_test_dice(1, 2, 3)
```

then calls to `d()` will successively return 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, etc.

---

In case you are wondering why `nonlocal` differs from `global` (which will happily create a global variable if one doesn't already exist), consider the following example:

```
def f():
    def g():
        def h():
            nonlocal i
            i = 1
```

Which scope should `i` be created in, `f`'s or `g`'s? With `global`, there is only ever one choice, as the global scope is unique. Rather than make an arbitrary choice (even a seemingly reasonable one like "create `i` in the closest nonlocal scope), Python simply refuses to make a choice and leaves it to the programmer to be explicit about which `i` should be used.

Comment: I actually missed out the definition of index, which is index = len(outcomes) in the very beginning of this code, and your comment solved my problem, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If the indentation is indeed wrong and `dice` is nested inside `make_test_dice`, this is not recursion but a simple decorator pattern. The function `make_test_dice` returns a `dice` function everytime it is called, while the `dice` function that is returned, in turn, needs to be called (since it is still a function) returns the output.

As for why you keep getting the same output, it has to do with the `index` variable which is defined as `nonlocal` in the scope of `dice` function. `nonlocal` means that whenever you will be changing the value of `index` it will refer to a `index` that resides in the outside scope of the `dice` function. Why so? Because each time you call `make_test_dice` a new instance of the `dice` function is generated, just like a new instance of a literal would be generated if it was returned from a function call. If it were not defined as `nonlocal` there would be no way of persisting the value of `index` between calls to `dice` and hence the returned number from `dice` would never change, which is what you are reporting to be happening. Check the definition of `index` is made at the correct place and the program should work as expected.

Comment: wow, your answer if of great help, thank you! I actually missed out the definition of index, which is index = len(outcomes) in the very beginning of this code, anyway, thanks for your help!